# PHP remove multidimensional array key on multiple conditions

Tags: php, arrays

I have a below PHP array in which you can see category/sub-category structure based on "parent_id" & "parent" element. 
Now the requirement is, on the basis of "menu_display_special = 1" condition, I want to delete that key as well as the keys which have this key's id as parent_id.

Note: If the "menu_display_special = 1" condition matches, it should remove the keys from category & sub-categories(if any) from the array.

**Result should return only one array element. i.e. id = 2378**

```
Array
(
    [35] => Joomla\CMS\Menu\MenuItem Object
        (
            [id] => 2375            
            [params:protected] => Joomla\Registry\Registry Object
                (
                    [data:protected] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [menu_display_special] => 1
                        )
                )
            [parent_id] => 2376
            [parent] => 
        )

    [36] => Joomla\CMS\Menu\MenuItem Object
        (
            [id] => 2377
            [params:protected] => Joomla\Registry\Registry Object
                (
                    [data:protected] => stdClass Object
                        (
                        )
                )
            [parent_id] => 2376
            [parent] => 1
        )

    [37] => Joomla\CMS\Menu\MenuItem Object
        (
            [id] => 2379
            [params:protected] => Joomla\Registry\Registry Object
                (
                    [data:protected] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [menu_display_special] => 1
                        )
                )
            [parent_id] => 2377
            [parent] => 
        )

    [38] => Joomla\CMS\Menu\MenuItem Object
        (
            [id] => 2380
            [params:protected] => Joomla\Registry\Registry Object
                (
                    [data:protected] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [menu_display_special] => 1
                        )
                )
            [parent_id] => 2377
            [parent] => 
        )

    [39] => Joomla\CMS\Menu\MenuItem Object
        (
            [id] => 2381
            [params:protected] => Joomla\Registry\Registry Object
                (
                    [data:protected] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [menu_display_special] => 1
                        )
                )
            [parent_id] => 2377
            [parent] => 
        )

    [40] => Joomla\CMS\Menu\MenuItem Object
        (
            [id] => 2378
            [params:protected] => Joomla\Registry\Registry Object
                (
                    [data:protected] => stdClass Object
                        (
                        )
                )
            [parent_id] => 2376
            [parent] =>
        )

)
```

**Code After var_export :**

```
array (
  35 => 
  Joomla\CMS\Menu\MenuItem::__set_state(array(
     'id' => '2375',
     'params' =>     
    Joomla\Registry\Registry::__set_state(array(
       'data' => 
      stdClass::__set_state(array(
         'menu_display_special' => '1',
      )),
    )),
     'parent_id' => '2376',
     'parent' => false,
  )),
  36 => 
  Joomla\CMS\Menu\MenuItem::__set_state(array(
     'id' => '2377',
     'params' => 
    Joomla\Registry\Registry::__set_state(array(
       'data' => 
      stdClass::__set_state(array(        
         'menu_display_special' => '1',
      )),
    )),    
     'parent_id' => '2376',
     'parent' => true,     
  )),
  37 => 
  Joomla\CMS\Menu\MenuItem::__set_state(array(
     'id' => '2379',
     'params' => 
    Joomla\Registry\Registry::__set_state(array(
       'data' => 
      stdClass::__set_state(array(
         'menu_display_special' => '1',
      )),
    )),
     'parent_id' => '2377',
     'parent' => false,
  )),
  38 => 
  Joomla\CMS\Menu\MenuItem::__set_state(array(
     'id' => '2380',
     'params' => 
    Joomla\Registry\Registry::__set_state(array(
       'data' => 
      stdClass::__set_state(array(        
         'menu_display_special' => '1',
      )),
    )),
     'parent_id' => '2377',
     'parent' => false,
  )),
  39 => 
  Joomla\CMS\Menu\MenuItem::__set_state(array(
     'id' => '2381',
     'params' => 
    Joomla\Registry\Registry::__set_state(array(
       'data' => 
      stdClass::__set_state(array(        
      )),
    )),
     'parent_id' => '2377',
     'parent' => false,
  )),
  40 => 
  Joomla\CMS\Menu\MenuItem::__set_state(array(
     'id' => '2378',
     'params' => 
    Joomla\Registry\Registry::__set_state(array(
       'data' => 
      stdClass::__set_state(array(
      )),
    )),
     'parent_id' => '2376',
     'parent' => false,
  )),
)
```

**Coding attempt : but it returns 2 array element i.e. 2381 & 2378. It should give me only 2378 as 2381 is child of 2377( which has menu_display_special value 1)**

```
 $listArray = array_filter($list, 
        function($v) use($list) { 
            return $v->params->get('menu_display_special') != '1' && ($v->parent == TRUE || $list[$v->parent_id]['params']['menu_display_special'] != '1');
        }
 );
```

Comment: "Show me what you got"- Alien head judge

Comment: @MohdAbdulMujib - stop being so demanding and just write his code for him already

Comment: @Kirtikumar What is your exact desired output from your sample data?  Where is your coding attempt?  Your question is not instantly clear to understand.

Comment: @mickmackusa have updated the question. can you please check it once?

Comment: Please show var_export data so that we don't have to manually rewrite your data. (Or a json string)  You must include a coding attempt.  I don't answer unattempted questions.  This is a site where developers ask and answer questions.

Comment: @mickmackusa  Added var_export data in description.

Comment: I like to help fellow Joomla users, but I want to see a coding attempt before I do anything.

Comment: @mickmackusa Added my code also..I think $list[$v->parent_id]['params']['menu_display_special'] != '1') this condition is getting failed.

Comment: That looks a lot like my pal @Nick 's deleted answer, but I'll take it.  I'll have a look after family time.

Comment: This is the Nick's answer :
echo "<pre>"; print_r(array_filter($listArrray, 
                     function($v) use($listArrray) { 
                         return $v['extra_data']['is_special'] == 0 && 
                                ($v['parent_id'] == 0 || $listArrray[$v['parent_id']]['extra_data']['is_special'] == 0);
                     }
                     ));
                               echo "</pre>";

It will be very grateful to me if you give me the solution/suggestion ASAP as I am stuck from long time & need to move on queued task which depend on this task. :)

Comment: @KirtikumarPawar what is the status of this question?  If I have solved your issue, please award the green tick to my answer.  If not, please clarify what is not quite right.  All questions should progress to a system-recognized resolution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your design requirements allow me to merge the conditions in my recursive function, so I've kept them separate to try to be ultimately accurate.

There is no return value and `$array` is preceded by a `&` to make it modify the originally passed input array.

Code ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/bNM61))

```
function recurse(&$array, $pid = null) {
    foreach ($array as $id => $item) {
        if (isset($item->params->data->menu_display_special) && $item->params->data->menu_display_special == 1) { 
            unset($array[$id]);
            recurse($array, $item->id);
        } elseif ($item->parent_id === $pid) {
            unset($array[$id]);
        }
    }
}    

$list = [
    35 => (object)[
        'id' => '2375',
        'params' => (object)[ 
            'data' => (object)[
                'menu_display_special' => '1'
            ]
        ],
        'parent_id' => '2376',
        'parent' => false
    ],
    36 => (object)[
        'id' => '2377',
        'params' => (object)[ 
            'data' => (object)[
                'menu_display_special' => '1'
            ]
        ],
        'parent_id' => '2376',
        'parent' => false
    ],
    37 => (object)[
        'id' => '2379',
        'params' => (object)[ 
            'data' => (object)[
                'menu_display_special' => '1'
            ]
        ],
        'parent_id' => '2377',
        'parent' => false
    ],
    38 => (object)[
        'id' => '2380',
        'params' => (object)[ 
            'data' => (object)[
                'menu_display_special' => '1'
            ]
        ],
        'parent_id' => '2377',
        'parent' => false
    ],
    39 => (object)[
        'id' => '2381',
        'params' => (object)[ 
            'data' => (object)[]
        ],
        'parent_id' => '2377',
        'parent' => false
    ],
    40 => (object)[
        'id' => '2378',
        'params' => (object)[ 
            'data' => (object)[]
        ],
        'parent_id' => '2376',
        'parent' => false
    ],
];

recurse($list);
var_export($list);
```

Output:

```
array (
  40 => 
  (object) array(
     'id' => '2378',
     'params' => 
    (object) array(
       'data' => 
      (object) array(
      ),
    ),
     'parent_id' => '2376',
     'parent' => false,
  ),
)
```

Comment: In the future, you can avoid downvotes if you post a complete, attempted, and reproducible question.  If you ever have a Joomla-specific question, please post it on Joomla Stack Exchange.